# How to overlay multiple bar chart datasets of different values over one column? [Excel 2016]

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Using Excel 2016:

My x-axis has 38 variables ('sites'), each with up to 9 datasets. I would like to combine these datasets into a single bar (clustered column) for each site. My issue is that the values of each dataset do not ascend/descent, meaning I cannot overlay them equally for each site. Is there a way of making the smallest value for a given site appear at the front (biggest at back and so on) when there are more than two datasets to deal with? If not, I will just have to stack it.

[image: Chart (currently split into up to 9 bars for each site - I want them to overlap smallest at front etc. as 1 bar)]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question you've already discovered-you can't do what you'd like to and still have a readable product.  So, I'd suggest you consider what you're trying to show-comparisons, aggregations, distributions?  Generally, you have 342 data points (38*9) that you're trying to represent.  Here are some possible alternatives:

To simply show each data point, consider an XY/Scatter Chart where each your datasets are stacked by site, this is almost identical to an overlayed, cluster bar chart without the bars.[image]

To highlight an important dataset across all of your sites, with all of your datasets present for context, modify the example above, with all colors grayed out, except for your subject of interest.[image]

To show micro and macro relationships, consider a panel/small multiples layout with a panel for each dataset with all 38 sites represented.  A common layout and scale allows for direct comparison.[image]

Finally, you can use a panel chart to highlight an important site across all the data sets like this [image]

Comment: Thank you very much - I will try these out. The X/Y Scatter Chart looks ideal, but I will try out some of the other variations out too!